# Remove a bad tag completely with html5lib.sanitizer

Tags: python, tokenize, html-sanitizing, html5lib, sanitizer

I'm trying to use html5lib.sanitizer to clean user-input as suggested in the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation#Sanitizing_Tokenizer)

The problem is I want to remove bad tags completely and not just escape them (which seems like a bad idea anyway).

The workaround suggested in the patch [here](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/issues/detail?id=62#makechanges) doesn't work as expected (it keeps inner content of a `<tag>content</tag>`).

Specifically, I want to do something like this:

Input:

```
<script>bad_thing();</script>
<style>* { background: #000; }</style>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
Lorem ipsum
```

Output:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
Lorem ipsum
```

Any ideas on how to achieve it? I've tried BeautifulSoup, but it doesn't seem to work well, and lxml inserts `<p></p>` tags in very strange places (e.g. around src attrs). So far, html5lib seems to be the best thing for the purpose, if I could just get it to remove tags instead of escaping them.

Comment: This depends how you want to select which tags to strip. Do you want to (a) strip only a few tags that you specify i.e. blacklisting or (b) strip all tags except those that you specify i.e. whitelisting or (c) something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is to also strip unwanted nested tags. It isn't pretty but it's a step in the right direction:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml import etree

html = '''
<script>bad_thing();</script>
<style>* { background: #000; }</style>
<h1>Hello world<script>bad_thing();</script></h1>
Lorem ipsum
<script>bad_thing();</script>
<b>Bold Text</b>
'''

l = []
doc = fromstring(html)
for el in doc.xpath(".//h1|.//b"):
    i = etree.Element(el.tag)
    i.text, i.tail = el.text, el.tail
    l.append(etree.tostring(i))

print ''.join(l)
```

Which outputs:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
Lorem ipsum
<b>Bold Text</b>
```